# How do you get the http status code of a Video File using libcurl in C++?

Tags: c++, video, curl, libcurl

The below libcurl code seems to work with image files (.gif, .jpeg, etc.) and text files (.txt, .xml, etc). The http status code is returned successfully for those files.

However it is having trouble with video files such as (.mp4). It appears to crash and prints out strange characters into the console.

How can i get the http status code of a video file? I would simply like to see if the video file is accessible. Thank you.

```
string httpStatusCode(string s)
{
    CURL *session;
    session = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_URL, s.c_str());

    CURLcode curl_code = curl_easy_perform (session);
    long http_code = 0;
    curl_easy_getinfo (session, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);

    if (http_code == 200 && curl_code != CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK)
        cout << "Success!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Failure!" << endl;

    curl_easy_cleanup(session);

    std::ostringstream buff;
    buff << http_code;
    return buff.str();
}
```

---

```
int main(void)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        cout << "Iteration # " << i << endl;
        string url = "http://www.example.com/video.mp4";
        cout << httpStatusCode(url) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those strange characters are actual contents of the file. If you want to just check the existence but not download the contents, issue a HEAD request - set `CURLOPT_NOBODY` option.

Comment: Thank you Igor, should I simply add the following line: curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); ?    Also, do you know why it crashes?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it fixed the issue! The will probably optimize the speed as well. It no longer crashes either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Igor. I've found a solution. By adding the following line, it will only issue a HEAD request instead of downloading the contents (which explains the strange characters being written to the log):

**curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);**